# A segment of code does not work as intended Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
 while True:
  print('who are you')
  name = input()
  if name != (str('joe')):
   continue
  print('hello joe whats the password?')
  if password == 'saltysea':
   break
print ('access granted')
```

the code gets stuck when i input joe: it keeps asking "who are you"

Edit: heres what i did to get the intended result

```
 password = '0'
while True:
  print('who are you')
  name=input()
  if name != 'joe':
   continue
  print('hello joe whats the password?')
  password=input()
  if password == 'saltysea':
  break

print ('access granted')
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Are you inputting *exactly* "joe"?  As an aside, `if name != (str('joe'))` is redundant... `'joe'` is already a string!

Comment: huh that's weird... ok i double checked that i posted the right code but i didn't sorry im new to this all but the second segment of code is the correct segment of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `continue` statement in Python returns the control to the
>   beginning of the while loop. The continue statement rejects all the
>   remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop and moves
>   the control back to the top of the loop.

(Compare [TP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm))

So in your case, you are iterating from top of while to the `continue` statement over and over. If you want to stop loop from executing after the `name` is not joe, use `break`

Your code should look something like this:

```
   while True:
           name = input('who are you')
           if name != (str('joe')):
                   break
           else:
                   password = input('hello joe whats the password?')
                   if password == 'saltysea':
                   print ('access granted')
                   break
```

Comment: I think the case is that the loop gets iterating over and over even if you input `joe`